# Set volatile environment variable

Tags: c#

In vbscript there is the ability to set an environment variable as volatile. It will persist for the duration of a login session only.

```
Set colVolEnvVars = objWShell.Environment("VOLATILE")
colVolEnvVars(C_VOL_ENV_VAR_VALUE) = value
```

These environment variables are stored in: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment

In c# you can set environment varaibles using:

```
 Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(envVar, value, EnvironmentVariableTarget);
```

The `EnvironmentVariableTarget` enumeration sets the type of environment variable. However it does not have a value for volatile.

I can read a volatile environment variable in c# using `GetEnvironmentVariable` however I cannot set one.

I know I could create a user environment variable and then delete it once it has been used. Or I could run a vbscript file from c# to get the desired results. Im hoping c# is powerful enough that there is a more elegant solution.

How can I produce this behaviour in c#?

Comment: I could just create the registry key myself using the registry class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment and Luaan's answer; I created a set volatile environment variable function using the `Registry` class.

```
void CreateVolatileEnvironmentVariable(string envVar, string value)
{
    RegistryKey rkeyVolatileEnv;
    rkeyVolatileEnv = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Volatile Environment", true);
    if (rkeyVolatileEnv != null)
    {
        rkeyVolatileEnv.SetValue(envVar, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no API in .NET to set volatile environmental variables.

That said, the implementation of the actual `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` is actually very simple (from .NET reference source):

```
using (RegistryKey environmentKey = 
       Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Environment", true)) {
           if (environmentKey != null) {
               if (value == null)
                   environmentKey.DeleteValue(variable, false);
                      else
                   environmentKey.SetValue(variable, value);
               }
           }
```

You can easily adapt this to use the `Volatile environment` key instead of `Environment`.

Portability also isn't an issue, really, since the other .NET platforms don't support global environmental variables in the first place (only the `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process` is supported). Maybe that would better for you anyway? Unless elevating, environmental variables are inherited by processes you start (and their children) - there is rarely a case where `Volatile environment` is desirable.